# How to read XML from .svc Webservice in Android?

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to read XML from .SVC webservice i am able to read the service i mean i am getting the data but data is not in XML format. Data look like this.

```
"\u003cPLAuthenticationWCF\u003e\u003cMobileAppKey /\u003e\u003cIsAuthenticated\u003e0\u003c/IsAuthenticated\u003e\u003cReason\u003eInvalid username or password.\u003c/Reason\u003e\u003c/PLAuthenticationWCF\u003e"
```

Now how to read this kind of XML in android please help me out. I search a lot but now found any useful solution. I am using below code to get data from .SVC webserive.

```
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/xxxxxx/" + method;
    String SOAP_METHOD = method;

    String soapMessage = "";
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, SOAP_METHOD);
        request.addProperty("xxxxxxx", UserName);
        request.addProperty("xxxxx", Password);
        request.addProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport
                .setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        /* Object */
        //result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        soapMessage = result.toString();
        readXML(soapMessage);
        return soapMessage;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logcat.e("UpdateProduct", "Error : " + e.toString());
        return soapMessage;
    }
```